# MIPS assembler error on importing MARS project in qtspim

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator, spim, qtspim

I've made a project in MARS that runs and compile well, but when i try to put it on qtspim (teacher requires it), it gives me a lot of errors.
Main errors are when i save and restore registers before and after a procedure call .

```
sw $a0,20($sp)
sw $a1,16($sp)
sw $a2,12($sp)
sw $t6,8($sp)
sw $s7,4($sp)
sw $ra,0($sp)
```

This is an example of where QtSpim stops. 
Error is

```
Read from unused memory-mapped IO address (0xfffffffc)
```

Why it behaves like this? All the project is under align 2. There are not case sensitive errors or error in file access (the code is  from a file-reading program).
How can i fix it?

Comment: This is the settings panel https://imgur.com/a/w9n7OfS

Comment: I need this for a project and i'm really  concerned about this error.

Comment: In the settings panel, add a check mark on "Enable Mapped IO". Beyond that, if you are writing to addresses in `$sp`, `mars` may set this up beforehand and `spim` may not. Step one inst in both and see what the `$sp` value is.